# Como melhorar esse código? Questão Simples em C

Tags: c

Eu tenho uma questão que pede para calcular um valor devido de cada carro por estacionamento e imprimir em uma saída tabular, ex:

```
Carro           Horas           Valor
1               2.0             2.0
2               3.0             2.0
3               4.0             2.5

TOTAL           9.0             6.5
```

Eu basicamente estava tendo problemas ao ler o valor de horas e imprimir em uma saída tabular os valores número do carro, horas e valor(O erro era por causa da leitura das horas interferir na saída tabular). Então, fiz esse programa com a estrutura switch mas acho que essa não é a melhor forma de resolver esse problema pois tive que criar uma variável para cada coisa(hora do carro 1, hora do carro 2, valor a se pagar do carro 1....). Alguma indicação?(OBS, eu necessáriamente preciso da função calcularTaxa, a função ImprimeTela não é necessária. Também não sei nada ainda sobre arrays, ponteiros e assim por diante, somente funções).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    
    double calcularTaxas(float);
    void ImprimeTela(int, double, double);
    
    int main(){
        double horas, horas1, horas2, a , b, c, totalHoras = 0, totalTaxa = 0;
        for (int cont = 1; cont <=3; ++cont){
            printf("Digite quantas horas cada carro ficou no estacionamento: ");
            scanf("%lf", &horas);
            switch (cont){
                case 1:
                    a = calcularTaxas(horas);
                    horas1 = horas;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b = calcularTaxas(horas);
                    horas2 = horas;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    c = calcularTaxas(horas); 
                    break;           
                default:
                    break;
                }
        totalHoras = horas + horas1 + horas2;
        totalTaxa = a + b + c;
        }
        for (int cont = 1; cont <= 4; ++cont)
            switch (cont){
                case 1:
                    printf("\n%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t\n","Carro", "Horas", "Valor");
                    ImprimeTela(cont, horas1, a);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ImprimeTela(cont, horas2, b);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ImprimeTela(cont, horas, c);
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    ImprimeTela(cont, totalHoras, totalTaxa);
                default:
                    break;
                }         
        return 0;
    }
    // função para calculo do valor a ser pago para cada carro
    double calcularTaxas(float horas){
        float valor;
        if (horas <= 3)
            valor = 2;
        else if (horas >= 20)
            valor = 10;
        else
            valor = 2 + ceil(horas - 3) * 0.5;
        return valor;
    }
    void ImprimeTela(int a, double b, double c){
        if (a == 4)
            printf("\n%s\t\t%.1f\t\t%.1f\t\t\n", "TOTAL", b, c);
        else
            printf("%d\t\t%.1f\t\t%.1f\t\t\n", a, b, c);
    }
```

Comment: Pense bem: se a partir de agora você precisasse registrar 5 carros você teria que alterar seu código colocando mais 2 cases? Não me parece uma boa solução. Após tratar cada carro você só precisa imprimir a linha referente a ele e acumular os valores para impressão do total ao final do programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que você tem variáveis como `algo1`, `algo2`, `algo3`, etc, é um forte indício de que provavelmente você precisa usar uma array. No seu caso, parece ser exatamente isso, pois você quer guardar uma determinada quantidade de horas referente a diferentes carros. Sendo assim, use um array de `double`.

Ao ler os dados das horas, você já pode ir computando o total.

E ao imprimir as horas, você pode calcular a taxa, pois me parece que essa informação só é relevante ali (se precisasse guardar as taxas também, eu criaria outro array, ou então usaria um `struct` contendo ambas as informações).

Enfim, ficaria assim:

```
double calcularTaxas(double horas){
    if (horas <= 3)
        return 2;
    if (horas >= 20)
        return 10;
    return 2 + ceil(horas - 3) * 0.5;
}

int main() {
    int qtd = 3;
    double totalHoras = 0, totalTaxas = 0;
    double horas[qtd];

    for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        printf("Digite quantas horas o carro %d ficou no estacionamento: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &horas[i]);
        totalHoras += horas[i];
    }

    printf("%-15s%-15s%s\n", "Carro", "Horas", "Valor");
    for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        double taxa = calcularTaxas(horas[i]);
        printf("%-15d%-15.1f%.1f\n", i + 1, horas[i], taxa);
        totalTaxas += taxa;
    }
    printf("\n%-15s%-15.1f%.1f\n", "TOTAL", totalHoras, totalTaxas);

    return 0;
}
```

Usei as opções de formatação do `printf`: no caso, `%-15s` alinha o texto à esquerda, ocupando 15 posições (e preenchendo com espaços), e `%-15.1f` alinha o número à esquerda, ocupando 15 posições e com uma casa após a vírgula.

Também mudei a função `calcularTaxas`, pois aquela variável `valor` não era necessária: você pode simplesmente retornar o valor dependendo de cada caso (e o `return` encerra a execução da função, eliminando a necessidade do `else`). Se bem que ela não valida valores negativos (*fica a dica de melhoria*).

E repare como os totais são calculados nos *loops* (o `totalHoras` também poderia ser calculado no segundo *loop*, nesse caso não faria diferença).

Exemplo de como fica a saída:

```
Carro          Horas          Valor
1              2.0            2.0
2              5.0            3.0
3              25.0           10.0

TOTAL          32.0           15.0
```

---

Como já dito, se você quer guardar também as taxas juntamente com as horas (para não ter que calculá-las toda hora, por exemplo), uma alternativa é agrupar esses dados em um `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    double horas;
    double taxa;
} DadosEstacionamento;

double calcularTaxas(double horas){
    if (horas <= 3)
        return 2;
    if (horas >= 20)
        return 10;
    return 2 + ceil(horas - 3) * 0.5;
}

int main() {
    size_t qtd = 3;
    DadosEstacionamento *dados = malloc(qtd * sizeof *dados);
    double totalHoras = 0.0, totalTaxas = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        printf("Digite quantas horas o carro %d ficou no estacionamento: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &dados[i].horas);
        dados[i].taxa = calcularTaxas(dados[i].horas);
        totalHoras += dados[i].horas;
        totalTaxas += dados[i].taxa;
    }

    printf("%-15s%-15s%s\n", "Carro", "Horas", "Valor");
    for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        printf("%-15d%-15.1f%.1f\n", i + 1, dados[i].horas, dados[i].taxa);
    }
    printf("\n%-15s%-15.1f%.1f\n", "TOTAL", totalHoras, totalTaxas);

    free(dados);

    return 0;
}
```

O restante é similar ao código anterior, a diferença é que eu calculo a taxa logo depois que leio a quantidade de horas, e já atualizo ambos os totais. Assim, no segundo *loop* eu apenas imprimo os dados.